# Terminal: Path to Network Drive in Applescript

Tags: terminal, applescript

I am trying copy a file up to a network drive in AppleScript.

Normally I would do..

```
do script "mv ~/Desktop/file.txt ~/Folder/file.txt"
```

What is the correct path to a network drive?  I normally connect with finder by doing:

```
tell application "Finder"
    open location "smb://user:password@netDrive/MyShare"
end tell
```

How do I do:

```
do script "mv ~/Desktop/file.txt smb://user:password@netDrive/MyShare/Folder/file.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax would be `smb://[<user>@]<workgroup>[:<port>][/]`

To answer your second question:

```
do shell script "mv ~/Desktop/file.txt smb://user:password@netDrive/MyShare/Folder/file.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
do shell script "mv ~/Desktop/file.txt smb://user:password@netDrive/MyShare/Folder/file.txt"
```

return 'No such file or directory'
Finder mounts network drives under the /Volumes/

```
do shell script "mv ~/Desktop/file.txt /Volumes/netDrive/MyShare/Folder/file.txt"
```